# Is it possible to add customization claim in Client Credential Flow?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, clientcredential

I'm working on Client Credential Flow to authenticate two applications but I want to add some information in access token. Can we customize claim and include it in access token ?

Answer (score 2):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create the custom claim in Azure AD**

Please follow the below steps to get the access token

You can get the Object ID of Service Principal ID like below

**Azure Portal>Azure Active Directory>Enterprise Application>Select your application**

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KEcs.png)

Change the value in manifest like below

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIn3f.png)

Create the policy using powershell like below

```
$Policy = New-AzureADPolicy -Definition @('{"ClaimsMappingPolicy":{"Version":1,"IncludeBasicClaimSet":"true", "ClaimsSchema": [{"Source":"user","ID":"customvalue","JwtClaimType":"customclaim"}]}}') -DisplayName "Demo123" -Type "ClaimsMappingPolicy"
Add-AzureADServicePrincipalPolicy  -RefObjectId $Policy.Id -Id '<Service Principle ID>'
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fepdC.png)

Generate the code and copy the code to generate the token via postman

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/Tenant ID/v2.0/authorize? 
&client_id=Client ID&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/htfsK.png)

Kindly change the value in Postman to generate the Token

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZSk5.png)

copy the Access token value without quotes from postman

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/N80kf.png)

Decode the same access token value in jwt.ms

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD1Bo.png)

Comment: Can you tell where/how did you put the value "TheJeshB2cAdmin" that finally comes in your "customclaim"